# How to check if multiple file exists in a directory

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to check if multiple file with same extension exists in a directory, if found perform the operation. Since file exists only accepts one argument as a filename, its not seems to be working for me.

I tried the following code.

```
set filenames [glob *.cpf]

      if {[file exists $filenames == 1 }  {
      file delete {*} [glob *.cpf]
}
```

This code didn't deletes the files eg: a.cp, b.cpf in a directory and seems to skipping this step.
Please suggest if i am missing something.

Dan

Comment: IMHO, you don't need `file exists` check itself, as the list of names returned by `glob` are nothing but the actual files present in the given directory as per given pattern.

Comment: Hello Dinesh,
I need to first check if file exists and then to execute file delete, other wise to run the main body of code (not pasted here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to check for the length of the received filenames and loop through (if u want) and delete as per you need.

```
set filenames [glob -nocomplain *.cpf]
# If length of 'filenames' is more than 1 means, multiple files avaialble
if {[llength $filenames]>1} {
    # Your file operations
    foreach fname $filenames    {
        # Loop through the file
    }
}
```

The flag `-nocompain` will help us in preventing any error messages if there is no matching pattern.

**Reference :**  [glob](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm#M8)